# How to add text below your background image?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqg70.png)
I want to set the background image which will display at complete viewport mode.
I have achieved this through body tag.

```
body { background-image: url(/picture.jpg); }
```

I also want to add text below the background image which will come at another section in the same webpage.
But since I have used background image using body tag, I couldn't able to write further texts after the image.
How could I achieve it?
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Make a `div` and put in that one?

Comment: I am new in this domain. Can you please guide me how to put a background image in div?

Comment: @AkanshaGautam, if you add a small screen shot, it would be helpful to understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be slightly modifying your HTML structure.

```
<body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- All your HTML goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <!-- Your required text comes here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Then you can modify your CSS.

```
body .content-wrapper { background-image: url(/picture.jpg); }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or just add the image itself instead of the `div.content-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div class="image">
        <img></img> 
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <!-- Your required text comes here -->
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    .image{ 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;"
}
img{ 
    some style
}
.text{ 
    some style
}

</style>
```

Comment: It will set the background image and add the text to it.
But I want to add text not in the image i.e., outside of it.
Setting background image through body tag doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: made some changes